# Weather webservice that returns HDD & CDD for a ZIP code and month?

Tags: web-services

I'm looking for a webservice that will accept two arguments, ZIP code and month, and returh the heating degree days (HDD) and cooling degree days (CDD) for that ZIP code and month. I am positive that the Weather Service (www.weather.gov) has this information -- I get it manually from their website every month.

What I'm asking is whether there is a webservice that does this already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After exhaustive research, I can now say, "No". Damn.

The data is available (http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/climatenormals/climatenormals.pl?directive=prod_select&subrnum=) but no one has set up a webservice.

Data is also available from www.degreedays.net

Answer (score 1):

Degree Days.net has just released a commercial API: http://www.degreedays.net/api/

You can do exactly the type of data lookup you mentioned, and there are other options too.

(I should mention that I work for the company that runs that service.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at the sourcecode of ForeCastFox, a forecast plugin for Firefox.

You can find it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/398).
From there you'll see how they ask to a webservice ("international weather forecasts from AccuWeather.com")

Olivier